# Opera blocks downloads beyond first per tab

Tags: download, opera

A few updates ago, I started noticing that whenever I download files through Opera it will only ever let me download one file per tab I open. If I were to click another link to download a file, the download dialog does not even show up.

Is there a setting somewhere that I can toggle to stop this behaviour?

Comment: Check the concerned website in *Settings > Advanced > Privacy and Security > Site Settings > Automatic Downloads*.

Comment: @harrymc This applies to all websites

Comment: Did you find anything to hint at the problem in "Automatic Downloads"?

Comment: @harrymc The option "Ask when a site tries to download files automatically after the first file" was toggled off. Toggling it on seems to fix the problem. Strange, as that is the opposite of what I'd expect that option to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of the comments on the post:

This option per-website is found at
*Settings > Advanced > Privacy and Security > Site Settings > Automatic Downloads*.

The option's name is
"Ask when a site tries to download files automatically after the first file".

The poster indicated that for him enabling the option solved the problem,
which seems the opposite of what should have happened.
This sounds like a bug in Opera that needs to be signaled to the
developers.